# How can I get my profile image with Facebook Unity SDK 7.0.3 Beta?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using Facebook Unity SDK 7.0.3 Beta and I'm trying to load my profile image:

```
FB.API("/me/picture", HttpMethod.GET, MyPictureCallback);
```

MyPictureCallback definition:

```
void MyPictureCallback(IGraphResult result)
```

In previous versions FBResult type was used instead of IGraphResult and it had a Texture property. IGraphResult doesn't have a property to get texture.

So how is it possible to retrieve my profile image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to generate the image URL, then use WWW class to download the profile picture itself

```
public string GetFBPictureURL (string facebookID, int? width = null, int? height = null, string type = null)
        {
                string url = string.Format ("/{0}/picture", facebookID);
                string query = width != null ? "&width=" + width.ToString () : "";
                query += height != null ? "&height=" + height.ToString () : "";
                query += type != null ? "&type=" + type : "";
                query += "&redirect=false";
                if (query != "")
                        url += ("?g" + query);
                return url;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

1. Add 'this.Texture = result.texture;' to the GraphResult constructor.
2. Add 'public Texture2D Texture { get; private set; }' to GraphResult.cs
3. Add 'Texture2D Texture { get; }' to IGraphResult.cs, as well as 'using UnityEngine;'

With the changes in those 2 clases, now your IGraphResult will contain the Texture that you had before, and you can continue working like nothing happened!

Let me know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the [latest version of the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity). Simply use the Texture field from IGraphResult.

```
FB.API("/me/picture", HttpMethod.GET, delegate(IGraphResult result) {
  if (result.Texture != null) {
    // use texture
  }
});
```